# Reordering a String according to given indexes

Tags: java

> if the input string="india"
>       the out put will be "niida" this means the indexex positions are {1,0,3,2,4};

```
class ReorderSt{
static String []arr=new  String[]{"Technoarck"};
    static int [] index= new int[]{1,0,3,2,5,4,7,6,8};

    static void record(){
        String []temp= new String[arr.length];
        //arr[i] should be present at index[i]
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
        temp[index[i]]=arr[i];
        //copy temp to array
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            arr[i]=temp[i];
            index[i]=i;
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       record();
        System.out.println("Recorded array is");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        System.out.println("modified index array is");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(index));
    }

}
```

> i got error ArrayIndexOutofbond 
>       in this line  temp[index[i]]=arr[i];

Comment: You are missing a number in the `index` array. Your string is `Technoarck` with 10 letters, but the  index array contain only 9 indexes

Answer (score 1):

Technoarck has length 10. Index from 0 to 9
But the input index is upto 8 only there.
Correct it and try.

Since it is an array of string with one string in it. arr [1] wil throw array out of bound.
It’s a string array not character array

Or use temp[index[i]]= arr[0].charAt[i]

Answer (score 1):

That is quite a bit of code, and you don't need any arrays for your desired transform. Take an input `String`, and an array of indices and use a `StringBuilder` to construct a new `String` value using the indices and `String.charAt(int)` to append values. Something like,

```
String input = "Technoarck";
int[] index = {1,0,3,2,5,4,7,6,8};
System.out.printf("Recorded input is %s%n", input);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i : index) {
    sb.append(input.charAt(i));
}
System.out.printf("Modified output is %s%n", sb.toString());
```

Comment: thanku my dear friend  for helping me to solve my problme